# Ag-grid how to use angular material component in plain js renderer

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am trying to use angular material component inside plain js renderer,
as stated in ag-grid document, using framework renderer is slow.

However, if I just put the material component code in plain js, it will not render the material component properly

```
class plainJsRadioRenderer {
  eGui: any;

  // gets called once before the renderer is used
  init(params) {
      // create the cell
      this.eGui = document.createElement('div');
      this.eGui.innerHTML = `<mat-radio-button>Option 1</mat-radio-button>`;
  }

  getGui() {
      return this.eGui;
  }

  // gets called whenever the cell refreshes
  refresh(params) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Above is my attempt, but it will just directly paste the `mat-radio-button` inside the grid cell without processing it.

So how to use material component with plain js renderer?
Thanks

Comment: u will have to add the required classes as well and import the module as well

Comment: I already import the module in angular module and inside component.ts. but still don't work

Comment: and required classes ?

Comment: Required classes did you mean the renderer class? if yes then I already put my class in the same component for the ag-grid

Answer (score 0):

when you give ag-grid `cellRenderer` a function it just calls the function with row specific params and puts the results into the `innerHtml` of the cell. but when you want to use the Angular component/directive tag (`<mat-radio-button>` is also a directive [github](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/radio/radio.ts)), Angular should render it for you. this is the missing part. because of this, ag-grid lets you use Components with the framework solution which renders the Component before putting it into the cell. so as I know you have three options:

1- use Component as renderer and pay the optimization cost.
2- make regular radio button like material ones with CSS.
3- ask the UX designer to design a simpler UI for the radio button.